# Regular expression to extract all occurance of text which are in a format ""display_url" = "https://example.com";"

Tags: regex

I wants to extract all occurance of text which are in a format **""display_url" = "https://example.com";"**
String on which I need to apply regular expression is json string.
There are other urls in string but I need just those urls which are display urls. The data is Json string from which I wants to extract data. string is something like this with long urls and other data also.

```
                   "config_height" = 1080;
                            "config_width" = 1080;
                            src = "https://bytesong.fdel3-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/290026768_727463948376235_3554188366257815869_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s1080x1080&_nc_ht=instagram.fdel3-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=uRmgxvUK4o8AX8Yw3TG&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT903HYu4JZXRI5RCKNXCnChAcZ1YmpbpjLIF-qnUJV_zw&oe=62BF9468&_nc_sid=83d603";
                        }
                    );
                    "display_url" = "https://bytesong.fdel3-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/290026768_727463948376235_3554188366257815869_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s1080x1080&_nc_ht=instagram.fdel3-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=uRmgxvUK4o8AX8Yw3TG&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT903HYu4JZXRI5RCKNXCnChAcZ1YmpbpjLIF-qnUJV_zw&oe=62BF9468&_nc_sid=83d603";
                    "edge_media_to_tagged_user" =                         {
                        edges =                             (
                        );
                    };
                    "fact_check_information" = "<null>";
                    "fact_check_overall_rating" = "<null>";
                    "gating_info" = "<null>";
                    id = 2868454391372266415;
                    "is_video" = 0;
                    "media_overlay_info" = "<null>";
```

Comment: What is the is data you shown here? Is it a string?

Comment: yes its a multiline string

Comment: Is it a json string?

Comment: It's a graphql response, not strictly a Json. I don't want to use graphql parser so trying to do using regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is I used below regex to capture display_url.

`"display_url" = "(https?.+?)";`

[Demolink](https://regex101.com/r/KQvBOk/1)